# Change Lucidworks Fusion 3.15 default cluster

Tags: solr, fusion, lucidworks

I have installed **lucidworks fusion 3.1.5** server in my computer. As you know default  solr version for this fusion is 6.6, but I have already configured existing zookeeper cluster with **solr v7.2.1**. After a lot of researches I have managed to connect the existing **solr 7.2** cluster with Fusion 3.1.5, But when fusion creates signal, connectors and other cors for my **solr 7.2** collections it save in the **default** fusion cluster(**solr 6.6**).
**How can I change this behavior?** for example: I need to save signals, logs and other cores which are connected with solr 7.2 in solr 7.2. Is there a way to change these fusion settings.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by pointing your fusion.properties configuration to your ZK and Solr instances.

default.zk.connect = 192.168.1.1:2181, 192.168.1.2:2181, 192.168.1.3:2181, 192.168.1.4:2181, 192.168.1.5:2181

default.solrZk.connect = 192.168.1.1:2181, 192.168.1.2:2181, 192.168.1.3:2181, 192.168.1.4:2181, 192.168.1.5:2181

Obviously, adjust the IPs/ports for the Solr and ZK server nodes.

Then make sure that group.default does not have solr and zookeeper listed as services to load.

group.default = api, connectors, ui

I would suggest to delete your instance and start fresh by exploding the archive, configuring fusion.properties and then starting up the instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I have done these steps regarding fusion  [documentation](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/3.0/Installation_and_Configuration/Distributed-Installation-Windows.html), but every time I get error during starting **api**. See api log error: `2018-07-17T21:03:43,376 - ERROR [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0:SolrLoadBalancer@54] - {} - There are no live Solr nodes available in SolrCloud cluster
2018-07-17T21:03:43,376 - ERROR [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0:SolrLoadBalancer@54] - {} - There are no live Solr nodes available in SolrCloud cluster`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the issue: I have run solr using localhost, without adding host parameter.